# Any optimization method suggestion for Core Animation applications?

Tags: ios, core-animation, performance

I'm testing animation method for magazine like media-centric app. My goal is

- smooth animation of hundreds of sprites
- with video playback
- and standard UI overlay over animation screen.

I'm considering Core Animation or OpenGL.

OpenGL is definitely faster, but integrating video playback within GL sprites is impossible yet as I know. (it requires video to texture feature)

So I'm digging Core Animation. But the performance was too bad. I tried simple gravity simulation with 256 of 11x10px, alpha-blended bitmap sprites. And I got only about

- 10 fps
- 5% device utilization
- 5% renderer utilization
- 0% tiler utilization.

The bottleneck is obviously on CPU code.

As I know, CA uses GL for compositing, and I used just single tiny bitmap. So this result is unreasonable. CA framework itself has huge overhead, but **I can't figure out where it is, and how to fix.**

I tried optimization. But there was only a few options. I tried explicit transaction, removing all additional interpolations. However, the performance did not get better. I tried explicit animation, but it was too hard to understand it's behavior. Maybe the bottleneck is there.

**Any optimization method suggestion?**

Here's my ticking source code: (tick called with `CADisplayLink`):

```
- (void)tick
{
 [CATransaction begin];
 [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:0.0f];

 CGRect bounds = [hostLayer bounds];
 CGFloat gravity = +9.8f * 0.1f;

 for (TestParticleSprite *tspr in spriteLayers)
 {
  CGSize mtn = [tspr motion];
  CGPoint ctr = [tspr position];

  mtn.height += gravity;  
  ctr.x  += mtn.width;
  ctr.y  += mtn.height;

  CGFloat over = ctr.y - bounds.size.height;
  if (over > 0.0f)
  {
   // Hit the ground!
   ctr.y  = bounds.size.height - over;  // Bounce.
   mtn.height *= -1.0f;       // Bounce.
//   mtn.width *= 0.95f;       // Lose energy.
//   mtn.height *= 0.95f;       // Lose energy.
  }

  [tspr setMotion:mtn];
  [tspr setPosition:ctr];
  [tspr removeAllAnimations];

//  // Tried explicit animation, but it was unable to make it work.
//  CATransform3D  t  = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(ctr.x, ctr.y, 0.0f);
//  CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
//  [anim setAdditive:NO];
//  [anim setCumulative:NO];
////  [anim setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:t]];
//  [anim setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:t]];
//  [tspr addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];
 }

 [CATransaction commit];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Run your code under Shark (part of the CHUD tools) and see where most of the time is being spent - that should give you a clue as to where to focus your optimisation efforts.

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is I don't know where I have to fix. I tried all methods in my knowledge. So I'm asking some additional optimization method :) (Sorry for my unclear question)

Comment: @Eonil: the whole point of profiling the code with Shark is to identify the "hot spots" - try it - you'll have a much better understanding of why your code is not running fast enough and you can then come back and ask specific questions about optimising just those expensive parts of the code.